# Serialize object with Gson while one of the object fields is already in raw json format

Tags: json, gson

One of the object fields contains json-formatted string: `"{\"field\"=\"value\"}"`, how to tell `GSon` to leave this field as it is? I'm trying to avoid extra conversions.

Comment: Please post your whole JSON structure

Answer (score 0):

You can set the data type of that parent field into String,